# net core Validation: diffrent type of result

Tags: rest, validation, asp.net-core

I am developing some Rest API using c# in net Core 3 that will be used by a REACT app.

For validation, I saw that three different types of objects are returned:

1) For rules defined in model (e.g. confirm password)

```
[Compare("Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I got this object:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|ff4cda9e-4dd30d18a2a38002.",
    "errors": {
        "ConfirmPassword": [
            "La password e la password di conferma non coincidono"
        ]
    }
}
```

2) For the password rules managed by IdentityProvider, I got this:

```
[
    {
        "code": "PasswordTooShort",
        "description": "La password deve essere almeno di 6 caratteri."
    },
    {
        "code": "PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric",
        "description": "La password deve contenere almeno un carattere speciale."
    },
    {
        "code": "PasswordRequiresDigit",
        "description": "La password deve contenere almeno un numero ('0'-'9')."
    },
    {
        "code": "PasswordRequiresUpper",
        "description": "La password deve contenere almeno un carattere minuscolo ('A'-'Z')."
    }
]
```

3) Finally, for custom errors added with ModelStat.AddModelError I got this object:

```
{
    "Key 1": [
        "error messagge 1-1",
        "error messagge 2-1"
    ],
    "Key 2": [
        "error messagge 2-1"
    ]
}
```

How can I handle all errors evenly?

Comment: The first object is a [ValidationProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-3.1) instance and the ouput can be redefined this way (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-failure-error-response) for more information). For the 2nd and 3rd objects, most likely the formatting comes from your code... Could you share the code of your controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 1st format to be everywhere, you can use the `ValidationProblem()` method in your controllers, like in this example:

```cs
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    foreach(var error in result.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("userCreation", error.Description);
    }
    return ValidationProblem();
}
```

Have a look at the multiple overloads of the `ValidationProblem` method for more customization.

On the other hand, if you don't like the 1st format, you can redefine it as explained in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-failure-error-response):

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
            // format the response as you wish
            var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
            result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml);

            return result;
        };
    });
```